What circuit could I use to extract energy from a 4-20mA signal?
I was reading about 2-wire signal isolation circuits, which are devices that only require connecting the two cables of the standard 4-20mA signal, and they generate the same 4-20mA signal on the output terminals. However, the manufacturer states that it doesn't require external power supply, as the device uses 4mA from the measured signal to power all internal circuits. I'm trying to imagine a circuit that can extract energy from a signal and measure the signal at the same time, but I'm having trouble visualizing something that can work. Does anyone have any ideas or has designed something like this? I'd love to see a design that can work if someone knows of one.

For a precision isolator you'd have a power path and a signal path. For low precision (say for isolating a signal to a valve that's inside a control loop) you could do open-loop with a transformer. The former is pretty much the same circuit as in any isolated loop-powered transmitter except that it is measuring a 4-20mA input current rather than the signal from a sensor.
In general you have a minimum voltage drop at the output, say 8V, which gives you a minimum of (say) 3.6mA * 8V or about 28mW to run your circuitry, including any losses in power conversion. There would also be some signal isolation components and (quite often) a microcontroller and even a display. Here is a typical block diagram of such a transmitter:

It's all pretty straightforward except the power isolation needs to have low quiescent current, which generally points to some kind of bespoke magnetics and circuitry since most DC-DC converters are not optimized for this kind of application.
If it's not obvious, the energy comes from the output circuit in this kind of isolator, not from the input, and the excess is burned up in the transistor. You can make the input voltage drop very low if you like.

Your answer was very helpful, but do you have a detailed design by any chance? So far, I've only been able to find descriptions of how to do it, but what I'm missing is an actual design that implements it, so I can better understand how this type of circuit works

@WalterPH Such design are typically proprietary. You can buy one and take it apart and reverse engineer it.

As a retired applications engineer, one of my jobs was making reference designs for such things to answer exactly this type of question. A search for "analog.com 4-20ma reference design" turns up such things as https://www.analog.com/en/resources/reference-designs/maxrefdes1161.html#rd-overview which can be purchased and used, and its design schematics, pcb, and parts list are also provided on web free of charge. That's just a quick search result... Companies like analog.com and ti.com sell the chips, so the application reference design examples are there to help customers succeed.
